# Can't change image in selected custom cell

Tags: ios, uiimage, tableview, custom-cell

I created a custom cell to display a text and 2 images, when the user selects the cell, the image is supposed to change. I can access the properties of the cell, but can't change them :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.check.image = setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"];
    [cell.check setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"]]; }
```

> cell.check is a UIImageView

Am i missing something?

Comment: Now what the heck is `cell.check.image = setImage:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom cell then you can override the function setSelected:animated: like so...

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {
        self.check.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"];
    } else {
        self.check.image = nil;
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to do anything in the tableView code to change this. It will just work.

A better alternative to this is to keep the image the same inside self.check.  Then you can just set hidden to YES or NO accordingly. This will be more performant also.

To have this so that you get multiple selections from the table then in the TableViewController put...

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

This will set it so that you can select multiple rows. One tap selects and another tap deselects.

To get the selected rows you can run...

```
NSArray *selectedRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Comment: The problem with that is, i need the image to remain changed, but, when i select another row, the previous one is deselected, and the image turns back to the old  one

Comment: Just turn on allowsMultipleSelection in the tableView. This will then set it so that one tap selects the cell and another tap deselects the cell. Then you can select as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling setImage and cell.check.image on the same line? Try this and see if the result is the same.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.check.image = setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"];
    [cell.check setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two issues in your code

1) This code :

`cell.check.image= setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked"];`

2) There is no extension provided for the image

Replace it with:

`cell.check.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"1355327732_checkbox-checked.png"];`

Comment: You do not need to use extensions when using the UIImage imageNamed: method and doing so will lead to other issues such as @2x and ~ipad and @2x~ipad images not being found. Leave the .png extension off so the proper image is used for different devices. The following is correct IF indeed there is a space in  front of the filename? cell.check.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@" 1355327732_ checkbox- checked"];