# Change image on select within tableview cell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to change an image within a cell when it is selected. Here is what I have in my view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "second_image")

}
```

This is where I set the image:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "first_image")

}
```

When I select the cell, the image does not update. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't update the image :(

Comment: Sorry, that gives an error saying that the cell has no member named bgImage

Comment: And your imageView is called bgImage? Can you post your code where you add the imageView to the cell.

Comment: Yup! I edited my question

Comment: What does your `CustomTableViewCell` code look like?

Comment: It looks exactly like this: https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/Cell-Expander/blob/master/Cell%20Expander/PickerTableViewCell.swift

Comment: If it does indeed look *exactly* like that, then you need to add a new IBOutlet for your `UIImageView` in the cell : `@IBOutlet strong var bgImage: UIImageView!`. If that's not there, then there is no `bgImage` member for it to reference.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly. I already have this outlet. It is the only difference.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844724/cant-change-image-in-selected-custom-cell

Comment: Wait a second...when you were doing `let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`, did you remember the `as! CustomTableViewCell` after it? If not, it may not have seen the member, since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns a general `UITableViewCell` and requires the typecast.

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt Thank you sooooooooo much!!!! Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yup! Done. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Try using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead ([documentation about it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:)). This will give you a reference to the current cell, rather than a reference to a new reusable cell.

So, according to your code above:

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

This typecast is **critical** because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `UITableViewCell`, which will not have the `bgImage` member.

Also, make sure that you have a member called `bgImage` that is a `UIImageView` in your `CustomTableViewCell` class by adding `@IBOutlet strong var bgImage: UIImageView!`, and that said `IBOutlet` is connected in your storyboard/xib.

Answer (score 10):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "second_image")}
```

For Swift 3+:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "second_image")}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 4):

Change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "second_image")
}
```

As per default this works to change the image

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "2")
```

Comment: Sorry, that gives an error saying that the cell has no member named bgImage

Comment: As default `cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "2")`this works to update the image for a cell, but you have extended your cell and are calling `bgImage`so you need to check your `CustomTableViewCell`. Otherwise I could provide you the example that I tried (the default way to change the image) if you want to.

Comment: Could this have something to do with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844724/cant-change-image-in-selected-custom-cell

Comment: It could... Post your custom cell code if you need help with it, or if you would like to use the regular way I can update my answer.

Comment: This is what is in my custom cell, almost exactly, the only difference is the image outlet: https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/Cell-Expander/blob/master/Cell%20Expander/PickerTableViewCell.swift

Comment: That one does not contain any imageView?

Comment: @RashwanL she did have the `UIImageView` added. That was a modification she made :)

Comment: @RashwanL Thank you sooooooooo much for all your help and time!

Answer (score 4):

Though it is too late. But i like to answer to participate in this world.
I was having problem with changing selected and deselected cell image of a table view. I solved it this way.
When tableview delegate method call then create instance of that cell by

```
  let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
```

instead of

```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
```

and use your desired image into your cell imageview.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 
        cell.btnImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "screenr.png")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
    if indexPath.row == 0
        cell.btnImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "screen.png")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply use the .hightlightedimage value for the imageView? I'm doing the following in my cellForRowAt func:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(indexPath.row).png")
cell.imageView?.highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "\(indexPath.row)g.png")
```

And I've just named the necessary images "0.png" and "0g.png" etc to make sure the image and highlighted image match up. Of course, that's a small static array, if you were using coreData with a larger array you could simply hold the imageName and the hightlightedImageName in the data set and pull the info from there.