# cellForRow(at: indexPath) returns nil Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I have `UITableView` with a custom cell `IconsTableViewCell` holding one `UIImageView` and one `UILable`.
If a row was previously selected, when user taps on a new row, the previous row is deselected and the label's textcolor for the new row should change.
 However, when I try to get a reference to the current cell using `indexPath`, the app crashes. I am stuck at this for the past few hours.

```
class EighthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")!
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")!

struct Item {
    var name:String // name of the rows
    var selected:Bool // whether is selected or not
    var amount: Int // value of the items
}
var frequency = [
        Item(name:"Every week",selected: false, amount: 0),
        Item(name:"Every 2 weeks",selected: false, amount: 0),
        Item(name:"Every 4 weeks",selected: false, amount: 0),
        Item(name:"Once",selected: false, amount: 0),
        Item(name:"End of tenancy cleaning", selected: false, amount: 0)
    ]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // retrieve indexPathForCellSelected from UserDefaults
   if let retrievedIndexPath = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: indexKey) {
    if let data1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: retrievedIndexPath) as? IndexPath {
    indexPathForCellSelected = data1

 /* Inform the delegate that the row has already been selected.

      When calling 'tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:', it will calculate the total amount depending on the type of cleaning:
           Weekly, End of Tenancy..etc
             Call calculateTotal() function which is using `indexPathForCellSelected`to calculate the total */
           self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForCellSelected!)

  // assign the indexPath retrieved to StructS.indexPath
       StructS.indexPath = indexPathForCellSelected

      // assign StructS.price to  self.frequencyTotalPrice
                self.frequencyTotalPrice = StructS.price

            // assign self.frequencyTotalPrice to FullData.finalFrequecyAmount
                FullData.finalFrequecyAmount = self.frequencyTotalPrice

       // assign a Checkmark to the row with the corresponding indexPathForCellSelected retrieved
         tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathForCellSelected!)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

         tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathForCellSelected!)?.imageView?.image = checkedImage

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathForCellSelected!) as! IconsTableViewCell
    cell.frequencyLabel.textColor = .black

        // assign frequency[indexPath.row].name to FullData structure
            FullData.finalFrequencyName = frequency[indexPathForCellSelected!.row].name

    //assign the row as Int value to a global var so as to determine which ViewController to unwind segue in 10th ViewController
    StructS.frequencyRowSelectedEighthVC = indexPathForCellSelected!.row
  }
 }

    // handle the selection of the row so as to update the values of labels in section header. 
   // if indexPathForCellSelected == nil, select a default type of cleaning for the first time
    if indexPathForCellSelected == nil {
        // construct an indexPath for the row we want to select when no previous row was selected ( not already saved in UserDefaults)
    let rowToSelect:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

        // select the row at `rowToSelect` indexPath. This will just register the selectd row, However,the code that you have in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not yet executed because the delegate for the tablewView object in the ViewController has not been called yet. 
      self.tableView.selectRow(at: rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)

        // inform the delegate that the row was selected
        // stackoverflow.com/questions/24787098/programmatically-emulate-the-selection-in-uitableviewcontroller-in-swift
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: rowToSelect)

        //assign the row as Int value to a global var so as to determine which ViewController to unwind segue in 10th ViewController
        StructS.frequencyRowSelectedEighthVC = rowToSelect.row
        print("the row that was selected is\(StructS.frequencyRowSelectedEighthVC) ")
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return frequency.count
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

   // configure the cell
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! IconsTableViewCell
        cell.frequencyLabel.text = frequency[indexPath.row].name
        cell.frequencyLabel.textColor = .gray
        cell.iconImageView.image = uncheckedImage
         return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !frequency[indexPath.row].selected {
            // this avoid set initial value for the first time
            if let index = indexPathForCellSelected {
                // clear the previous cell
                frequency[index.row].selected = false
                tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.accessoryType = .none
                tableView.cellForRow(at: index)?.imageView?.image = nil
            }
            //mark the new row
            frequency[indexPath.row].selected = true
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

            //assign checked image to row
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = checkedImage

            //evaluates to nil when trying to get a reference to the cell at the selected indexPath
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! IconsTableViewCell   
            cell.frequencyLabel.textColor = .black

            //save indexPathForCellSelected in UserDefaults
            if indexPathForCellSelected != nil { 
                // used to check if there is a selected row in the table
                let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: indexPathForCellSelected!)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: indexKey)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } // end of if indexPathForCellSelected
        }
    }
} //end of class
```

Comment: Hi Please check the link may this can solve your problem..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621076/change-image-on-select-within-tableview-cell-swift

Comment: Are you serious to call `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` 5 times to get always the same object? The main issue (and very bad habit) is that you are going to manipulate the cell (the *view*) directly. **Don't do that**. Create an appropriate *model*, manipulate that and reload the table view.

Comment: try to use `self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! IconsTableViewCell` to get the cell at indexpath.

Comment: @vadian could you show in code? or point me to a tutorial that is describing what you are saying. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Actually you got a `selected` property in your model. Do all the settings depending on `selected` in `cellForRow`.  In `didSelect` toggle `.selected` and reload the table view. And if you have only one section save only the (`Int`) row in UserDefaults rather than the whole index path using the cumbersome archiver.

Comment: @vadian  All settings depend on the selected property. I will add the model to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a property `selectedRow`. By default the first row is selected.

  ```
  var selectedRow = 0
  ```
- In `viewWillAppear` read the selected row from UserDefaults and reload the table view

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      selectedRow = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: indexKey)
      frequency[selectedRow].selected = true
      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRow` set color, image and accessory view depending on the `selected` property

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell" for: indexPath) as! IconsTableViewCell
      let freq = frequency[indexPath.row]
      if freq.selected {
          cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
          cell.imageView?.image = checkedImage
          cell.frequencyLabel.textColor = .gray
      } else {
          cell.accessoryType = .none
          cell.imageView?.image = uncheckedImage
          cell.frequencyLabel.textColor = .black
      }

      cell.frequencyLabel.text = freq.name
      return cell
  }
  ```
- In `didSelectRowAt` compare the actual index path with `selectedRow`. If they are not equal set the `selected` property of the former selected cell to `false` and of the new selected cell to `true`. Then set `selectedRow` to the row of the index path, save the row to `UserDefaults` and reload the table view.

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      if indexPath.row != selectedRow {
          let previousIndexPath = IndexPath(row:selectedRow, section:0)
          frequency[selectedRow].selected = false
          frequency[indexPath.row].selected = true
          selectedRow = indexPath.row   

          UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRow, forKey: indexKey)
          tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath, previousIndexPath], with: .none)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: A tap on an already selected cell should not unselect it. It should have no effect. In viewWillAppear, I select first row by default, assign checkmark to it. Then, whenever a user taps on a row, if the row is already selected, nothing happens. If the user taps on a a new row, the previous, it is selected, it is assigned a checkmark, the previous row is unselected, its checkmark is removed.

Comment: It's just an example to show what is possible. Feel free to delete the `else` branch and put the last two lines in the `if` scope. But then you don't need the `not selected` case and can remove the related code, too.

Comment: very elegant solution. You're a star

Answer (score 0):

I would try this (assuming you have an array of `Item` structs):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let item = myItemArray[indexPath.row]
   (cell as! IconsTableViewCell).frequencyLabel.textColor = // get the color from your item selection state here
   ... // do other configurations to your cell
}
```

Comment: do you know why my code evaluates to nil? If I print the `indexPath`, it does print the output. However, as you can see in my question this code evaluates to nil .   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! IconsTableViewCell

Comment: Like already explained above, you should **never** call `cellForRow` yourself. Use `indexPath` to get to your `Item`, change it, and then reload your table.

Comment: @Koen ***never*** is not really true. Calling `cellForRow` is not evil per se, I wrote *... 5 times* and it's *very bad* to *manipulate the cell (the view) directly*